# How to change function variable in a nested function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change value of a variable declared inside a function in a nested function. But it's not working. Here's an example

```js
function foo() {
  var str = "";

  function foo1() {
    str = "hello";
  }
  foo1();

  alert(str); // it shows nothing
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="foo()">
```

Comment: Where is your function call in code ?

Comment: you didn't call `foo1`

Comment: It's onclick on html element.

Comment: I've added your code to code snippet, and it works as expected

Comment: @CodeManiac I don't know what's happening but now it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set your string to the return value of `foo1()`.

```
function foo() {
    function foo1(){
        return "bar";
    }
    var str = foo1();
    alert(str);// it shows "bar"
}

foo();
```

Comment: Thanks it worked on this code snippet. but i can't access it in my project. I am trying to do something like calling a function in navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function that return the coordinates). I need that coordinates to be assigned in a string.

Answer (score 0):

What you defined inside the function exists inside the function, there is no way to access the inside function currently, either move the code outside and function and call or rewrite the function and from the function call the inner function, both are shown below!

```js
function foo() {
  var str = "";

  function foo1() {
    str = "hello";
  }
  foo1();
  alert(str); // it shows nothing
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="click"/>
```

```js
var str = "";

function foo1() {
  str = "hello";
}

function foo() {
  foo1();
  alert(str); // it shows nothing
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="click"/>
```

Comment: I know what you are trying to say. I have called the function onclick on a button. and nested function is being called . I will edit my code!

Comment: @SaranshKhurana added the button, seems to work fine!

Comment: your first "non-working" example worked fine for me when i clicked run.